# angular observable async/ngrxLet pipes don't subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following stream  in my application, and apparently my pipe observable is not subscribing with the `async` pipe.

**ts**

```
type Formatter = (arr: string[]) => string[];
@Input() user: User = new User();
@Subjectize('user') user$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
private reformatList = new Subject<Formatter>();

list$: Observable<string[]> = this.reformatList.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.user$),
  map(([callback, user]: [Formatter, User]) =>
    callback(
      Object.entries(user.features).reduce(
        (acc: string[], [key, value]: [string, any]) => {
          const excludedKeys = ['key1', 'key2'];
          if (excludedKeys.includes(key)) return acc;
          value > 0 ? acc.push(key) : acc;
          return acc;
        },
        [],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  tap((res) => console.log),
);


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.reformatList.next((res) => res);
}
```

**html**

```html
<ng-container *ngrxLet="list$ as list">
<!-- I also tried with the async pipe as follows -->
<!-- <ng-container *ngIf="(list$ | async) as list"> -->
  <mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of list">
      <mat-icon> check </mat-icon>
      {{ item}}
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
</ng-container>
```

When the user toggle a `button` and `onInit` `Subject.next()` is called with different `callbacks` functions to modify items in the list.

If I run the app with the code above I don't see anything and I can't see the log, while if I put `this.list$.subscribe(console.log)` in the `ngOnInit()` I can see the logs in the console and the pipe works as expected

**UPDATE**
If I change the `Subject` into a `BehaviorSubject` the code works, so it must have to do with some of the difference between the two, but I think this should work with simple `Subject`

Comment: Well, you are not using the `async` pipe anywhere in your example. It is missing, hence no subscription is in place and the observable does not execute.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner I'm using `ngrxLet` which should behave like the `async` pipe in this example. I tried with the `async` too though. I edited the question to include the `async` version!

Comment: @PhilippMeissner I updated the question, using a `BehaviorSubject` instead of a simple `Subject` the code works, so there's no issue in the template

Comment: @Killua iirc the template isn't ready in `ngOnInit`. When you call `this.reformatList.next(...)` there is no subscriber yet. You should try with a later life cycle hook, e.g. `ngAfterViewInit`. Or introduce replaying, like you did with the change to `BehavioSubject`.

Comment: @churill please post as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already found a working solution I simply explain why your code didn't work. Just so you can close the question and maybe it's helpful for future readers too.

In `ngOnInit` the template is not yet initialized. `@Input`'s are not bound, `ViewChildren` are not loaded and pipes like `async` are not yet active.
When you call `this.reformatList.next(...)` the async-pipe hasn't yet subscribed to your observable, so the emission is lost.

You either need to add a replay-mechanism (`ReplaySubject`, `BehaviorSubject` or `shareReplay`-operator) or call `this.reformatList.next(...)` in another life cycle hook, e.g. `ngAfterViewInit`.